# how to label images in the right order for keras image classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is my code:-

```
test_batches_1 = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=test_path_1, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10, shuffle=False)


m_p = model.predict(x=test_batches_1, steps=len(test_batches_1), verbose=0)
```

where model refers to a vgg16 model minus the last layer and a custom dense layer with softmax function.

```
model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False    
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))
```

Now, the predictions are supposed to come alphabetically.

I have the following images in my folder

```
cat.14.jpg
cat.2.jpg
```

Predictions for cat.14 precedes cat.2

How to make sure it doesn't happen and 14 comes after 2?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change filenames. When you set `shuffle=False`, the files are sorted alphabetically, according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory).

> **shuffle**   Whether to shuffle the data (default: True) If set to False, sorts the data in alphanumeric order.

Alphabetically, `'cat.14.jpg'` comes before `'cat.2.jpg'`:

```
sorted(['cat.14.jpg', 'cat.2.jpg'])
```

```
['cat.14.jpg', 'cat.2.jpg']
```

Comment: Is there any way to change it? like cat_14 or cat_1_4?

Comment: You can rename the files in any way you like.

Comment: so that 14 comes before 2 was what i meant